# Average every nth row in Libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

simple problem, but I cannot figure it out.

I have a simple column (with many values) in a spreadsheet.

How can I calculate the average every 2 rows?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Just create average for the line, corresponding to this line and for the previous, stretch it and ignore every second line.

Comment: Thanks! I though it exists a king of  `range average` function.

Comment: Instead of ignoring every other line, you could make the calculation only display every other line: `=IF(MOD(ROW();2)=1;"";AVERAGE(A2:A3))` and copy and paste down.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution:

- enter the formula manually in the first and the third row;
- select rows 1-4
- and drag down.

LO will add the formula according the pattern in the selection, leaving out every second row.

EDIT: Example with Screenshots

1. Enter data:

   [image]
2. Enter first formula:

   [image]
3. Enter second formula (or paste the first one):

   [image]
4. Select first four value/formula rows (here, i increment both the data and the formula column by dragging - LO Calc is smart enough to increment both columns independently):

   [image]
5. Result with both columns automatically incremented:

   [image]

Comment: mmm it doesn't work. If I do what you said, LO adds the formula in each row below the selection.

Comment: Did you explicitly select rows 1-4 including the empty lines 2 and 4? Based on your screenshot, you would have to select cells `C2:C5` (since your data starts in row 2). I've just double-checked - it should work with a current LO version, tested on Ubuntu LInux as well as Win7.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but I cannot make it works. If I follow exactly your instructions, LO fills each row after the selection. Don't really know what could be the problem (LO version 4.3.3.2 on Debian).

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the sheet after dragging down the cell selection block?

Comment: @matteo, this works but you have to select the cell with the average as well as the following empty cell and only those. Start dragging the two cells down together (or 4 if you want to average every 4th cell)

Answer (score 2):

I have a simpler solution.

I'll demonstrate it for the average of every 5 rows.

Steps are as following:

1. First write the formula for the average of the first 5 rows.

   [image]
2. Drag it downward to get the average for the whole column. You can also do it by double-clicking on the bottom-right corner of the cell containing the average formula (in this example, B2)

   [image]
3. Select the column containing the average, and go to DATA --> STATISTICS --> SAMPLING

   [image]
4. Select the C2 cell in "Results to" and select "Periodic" as the sampling method with period "5". Click OK to get your desired results.

   [image]

Comment: Nice! Would you mind cutting those print-screens? There is no point for showing 50 lines in the first two cases, it'll make your answer even better.

Comment: Thanks @dedObed for your suggestion. I have implemented it.